# Xcode project with Parse cocoapod won't compile: "Unknown command tag name"

Tags: parse-platform

Like the title says, eager to start with Parse, but unable to compile it in my Xcode project. Could someone please help me out?

Xcode version: **6.1.1**
Cocoapods version: **0.35.0**

This is my Podfile

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

workspace 'ParseTest'

inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'FlatUIKit', :head
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'INTULocationManager'

xcodeproj 'ParseTest.xcodeproj'
```

And these are the errors I get when building my project:

Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFAnalytics.h:142:2: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h:29:10: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h:38:21: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h:42:26: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h:232:2: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h:748:1: Conflicting return type in declaration of 'delete:': 'void' vs 'BOOL' (aka 'bool')
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject.h:748:28: Conflicting parameter types in declaration of 'delete:': '__strong id' vs 'NSError *__autoreleasing *'
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject+Subclass.h:40:6: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject+Subclass.h:43:6: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFObject+Subclass.h:45:6: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFQuery.h:130:2: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFQuery.h:481:2: Unknown command tag name
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h:17:15: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h:18:15: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h:19:15: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h:20:15: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h:21:15: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PF_Twitter.h:22:15: Declaration of instance variables in the interface is deprecated
Pods/Parse/Parse.framework/Headers/PFTwitterUtils.h:225:2: Unknown command tag name

Comment: I presume you are using the latest SDK (1.6.0) and you have included all the libraries specified in the tutorials?

Comment: Yes I am using latest version. I didn't include anything other libraries then the ones from de pods listed in my Podfile. Half a year ago this worked. Maybe something has changed since then?

Comment: Yeah sorry I posted and only then realised it was an old thread..haha sorry